# Programatically created button missing rounded corners

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I'm having a big issue here. I've created a couple of buttons programmatically. The appear on the screen but some preferences are missing.

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDown];
    }

    if (capturedImageOneData == nil) {
        capturedImageOneData = image;
        [self resizeImage:image];
        self.capturedImageOneSmall = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        self.capturedImageOneSmall.frame = CGRectMake(3091, 50, 160, 120);
        [self.capturedImageOneSmall setBackgroundImage:capturedImageResized forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.capturedImageOneSmall addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.capturedImageOneSmall.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.capturedImageOneSmall.tag = 401;
        [self.capturedImageOneSmall addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.capturedImageOneSmall];
```

As you can see, I did some customising to the button. But for example, the cornerRadius is not showing in the picture (sharp edges stay).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
self.capturedImageOneSmall.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```